# Configure Jira notifications for only mentions and assigns

Tags: jira

How would I configure notifications for a Jira project in a way that the only e-mails that go out anymore are about:

- Getting @-mentioned in an item description or a comment
- Getting assigned to an item

The rationale here is that I only want push (e-mail) notifications for things that are actionable to me (e.g. if I need to respond or do something).

Preferably in a way that only some users can get this scheme (whereas others can keep the default, spammy scheme).

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

By default you will receive notification of any @mentions, so it is just the assignment emails that need work.

JIRA doesn't do 'per user' notification schemes, only setting them at a project level. This makes changes that only affect some users tricky.

One approach would be to set all the "spammy" notifications to go to a group that includes every except yourself. But leave "Issue Assigned" with "Current Assignee" so those notifications still go out. This may increase the amount of emails to the users who are in that group however, since it is less targeted than current assignee/reporter.

[image: Notification example]

If you haven't already, it might be worth seeing if other users are happy to reduce the number of emails JIRA sends so you can disable them for everyone. JIRA is a little too chatty by default anyway.